# one LUIS model refusing to display intents

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I've been modifying a model in Luis for a few days now - adding intents, removing intents, adding utterances and the odd Feature. All been fine, but it's been getting progressively slower and shower showing me my intent list (and any other list related to the model). It's now a good 2 hours I've been waiting or it to show my intents.
Other models work fine and show fairly rapidly.
Model has approx. 380 intents, just North of 3,000 utterances and probably about 20 features.

Is there an aspect of a model that can seriously slow down its ability to render it onscreen for editing.
Additionally, the Train, Publish and Test buttons are greyed out and unavailable - again just for this model.

I've tried exporting and importing as a new version with same effect - also imported as new app; same.

Last thing I did was to move approx. 20 utterances from one intent to another intent using the 'move' option in the utterance option list next to the edit/Delete options.

Any help greatly appreciated as I'm on a bit of a deadline with this.